# Implement the vector insert function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to implement vector's insert function in c++. The basic idea is

1. initialize a tmp_vector with the size of the new array; 
   2.copy the original data into a tmp_vector;
2. delete the old vector; copy the
3. tmp_vector to new_vector

Here's my code:

```
double* Vector::insert(int index, double *newNum, int newNum_size)
{
    //insert into empty vector

    if(size == 0){

        //if there's enough memory to hold newNum
        if(newNum_size < capacity)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < newNum_size; i++)
            {
                data[i] = newNum[i];
            }
        }
    }

    //expand the vector
    if(size != 0){

        double *tmp_vector = NULL;
        try{
            tmp_vector = new double(size+newNum_size);
        }
        catch(bad_alloc &e){
            cerr << "Vector::insertion(): " << e.what();
        }

        //move the vector to tmp
        for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tmp_vector[i] = data[i];
        }

        //copy the tmp_vector pointer to newNum pointer
        tmp_vector[size+newNum_size] = *newNum;

        //realease the memory from data
        delete[] data;

    }

    return newNum; 

}
```

However, it gives me a compile error when I call it from main

```
myVector.insert(0,1.0,1);
```

The error is "Cannot initialize a parameter type 'double' with an rvalue of type 'double'". What does this mean?

Comment: I don't think `insert(0,1.0,1)` match `insert(int index, double *newNum, int newNum_size)`.

Comment: The expression `new double(size+newNum_size)` doesn't do what you think it does, it only allocates *one* `double` value and initializes it. There are also other things that seem weird, like you deleting `data` but no assigning to it.

Comment: Most of the code you posted is irrelevant. Better create an MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
(int index, double *newNum, int newNum_size)
(0,            1.0,                 1)
```

I think the problem is that **1.0** is not a double[*]... it's just a double.

Answer (score 0):

In the signature of your function:

```
double* Vector::insert(int index, double *newNum, int newNum_size)
```

you are expecting **double pointer/an array of doubles**, whereas in `insert(0,1.0,1)` you are passing a **single double value**.

Moreover, I don't see where did `size` variable come from. Provided you would have it declared inside the function/passed to a function, this would be incorrect: `tmp_vector = new double(size+newNum_size)` and what you want is probably: `tmp_vector = new double(size*newNum_size)` (the latter would allocate `newNum_size` times `size` memory, i.e. space for your array).

Comment: The first problem you raised is correct. I want to insert not just one double but also an array of doubles, but I didn't handle that well. As for the second one, "size" is declared as private data member so I didn't include it in this function. I don't quite understand why it's "size*newNum_size" because I thought after the insertion, the new size should be the original size plus the size of the array that has been inserted.

Comment: No, I haven't. Fell asleep right after I posted it.

Comment: Try to modify it then and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am stuck on the 2nd situation (if the vector is not empty case). After I initialize a tmp_ptr (which has the capacity that can hold the post-insertion vector), I don't know how to copy the value from both the original vector and the *newNum. I was thinking of using a for loop to copy the first-part of the original array, then let the *newNum point to the inserted position, then copy the rest of the original array. But I feel that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the STL implementation? This way you can avoid unnecessary complications. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/